# getPrivateNetworkVrfs" is not a valid method for this service

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are trying to use the method `getPrivateNetworkVrfs()` found in the doc
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account. But we are getting error like

```
client.call('SoftLayer_Account', 'getPrivateNetworkVrfs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 237, in call
return self.transport(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 187, in __call__
raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(Client): Function ("getPrivateNetworkVrfs") is not a valid method for this service.
```

But we are able to use method like "`getNetworkVlanSpan`" successfully

Please let us know, whether we are missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Does your account have a Direct Link? My understanding is that the VRF would only exist on accounts with an active Direct Link connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not understand what is the direct link? If that is any specific setting enabled. How to check whether direct link is enabled for user in softlayer using Softlayer API?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [SoftLayer_Account::getPrivateNetworkVrfs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateNetworkVrfs) method is deprecated, if you would like to check or get this kind of information, you need to submit a ticket

**Related Forum:**

- [Is there an API to check whether an account has VRF or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155803/is-there-an-api-to-check-whether-an-account-has-vrf-or-not)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any equivalent method which does similar function like getPrivateNetworkVrfs ()  or any indirect way of finding out whether VRF enabled for the account?. Please let us know.

Comment: No, if you requested this before, keep in mind that the account has it. There is no way to check through API/Portal. It's really necessary to submit a ticket to get this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks for the response